# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 74404 into shape (6764,1691,1)

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, 3d, reshape

My `df` shape is 2D `(6764, 11)`.

I want to reshape it into 3D with 1691 time steps (i.e., 1/4 of 6764)

```
df = df.values.reshape((df.shape[0], 1691, df.shape[1]))
```

I get the error: **ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 74404 into shape (6764,1691,11)**

Why I get size **74404**??? I get is 1674*11, but why is doing this multiplication?

**edit**

I actually want to reshape my data into [6764, 1691, 11], which is the dimension required for an LSTM model. This dimension stands for [Samples, TimeSteps, Features] where samples are the number of data points, time steps the number of data points I want to analyse/predict, and 11 the inputs (columns) I am using. Any advise on how to achieve this shape without getting the error ? my reference is [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/)

Answer (score 0):

From 2D dataframe you have an array of 6764 x 11 = 74404 values.

**Multiplication indicates the number of values you have in the array/dataframe.**

from your code (df.shape[0], 1691, df10.shape[1])) it would generate 6764 x 1691x 11 = 125817164 which is not matching to input array values thats why you are getting an error.

Considering you want 1691 series you can reshape your data into (1691 x 4 x 11)

```
df = df.values.reshape((1691,4, df.shape[1]))
```

If you need only 1st column that is 6764 values to reshape then use below code although it will generate 2D array with (1691,4) shape.

```
df = df['column_name'].values.reshape((1691,4))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually want to reshape my data into [6764, 1691, 11], which is the dimension required for an LSTM model. This dimension stands for [Samples, TimeSteps, Features] where samples are the number of data points, time steps the number of data points I want to analyse/predict, and 11 the inputs (columns) I am using. Any advise on how to achieve this shape without getting the error ? my reference is https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/